# php, how to get value from 2 tags?

Tags: php, xpath

Hello i am trying to get the result "3" using this xquery in PHP
`....td[2]/span/b`

at this moment he only return this `<b class="price">3</b>`

my code is

```
        $result_rows = $xpath->query($xquery);
    foreach ($result_rows  as $result_object)
    {   
        return strstr($result_object->nodeValue);
    }
```

it is possible to get the exact value "3" without using strstr function?

thanks

Comment: have no idea why i got 1 downvote...but ok....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xPath has a text() function. Your xPath query would look something like this :

```
td[2]/span/b/text()
```